# Странное поведение функции read() в символьном драйвере

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

Моя функция `read()` для символьного драйвера

```
static ssize_t my_driver_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Function read() works and received %zu characters\n", count);

    if (copy_to_user(buf, my_driver_buf, count)) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error in function copy_to_user()\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    *f_pos += count;
    return count; 
}
```

Ну и функция `write()` на всякий случай

```
static ssize_t my_driver_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Function write() works and received %zu characters\n", count);

    if (copy_from_user(my_driver_buf, buf, count)) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error in function copy_from_user()\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    *f_pos += count;
    return count;
}
```

Мой буфер, который объявлен глобальным

```
static char my_driver_buf[140000];
```

Собственно проблемы с данными функциями(на которые указывают члены структуры `file_operations` в символьном драйвере):

Когда я пишу такую команду `strace echo hello > /dev/my_driver`(файл устройства), получается такой вывод(обрезал до последних строчек)

```
write(1, "hello\n", 6)                  = 6
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

А когда я пишу такую команду `strace cat /dev/my_driver`, то вывод получается такой(обрезал текст сверху и снизу)

```
read(3, "hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072hello
) = 131072
read(3, "hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072hello
) = 131072
read(3, "hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 131072
write(1, "hello\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072hello
) = 131072
```

(повторяется пока я не нажму Ctrl+C)

Собственно назревают вопросы:

1) почему переменная `count` в функции `write()` равна `6` (hello\n), а когда я вызываю фунцию `read()`, то `count` там равна `131072`(hello\n\0\0\0....), а не `6` ?

2) почему функция `read()` попадает в цикл и вызывается снова, хотя я пишу `return count;` в конце функции `read()`, что является оптимальным вариантом(все данные получены) ?

3) зачем нам нужен `loff_t *f_pos`, если в файл мы все равно ничего не записываем (`если я правильно понимаю, то мы работаем с буфером пользовательского пространства, который предоставляет ядро и с буфером, который мы сами создаем, в нашем случае - my_driver_buf`) и нам необязательно знать позицию в нем (в данном примере по крайне мере) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) почему переменная `count` в функции `write()` равна `6` (hello\n), а когда я вызываю фунцию `read()`, то `count` там равна `131072`(hello\n\0\0\0....), а не `6` ?

Потому что и то и другое сообщает программа пользовательского пространства, передовая соответственно как последний аргумент вызовов `read`/`write`. Если объяснять на пальцах, то `echo` говорит «у меня есть буфер длинной 6 байт и я хочу записать его на устройство», а `cat` сообщает системе «у меня есть буфер 128к и я хочу прочитать в него столько сколько есть на устройстве».

> 2) почему функция `read()` попадает в цикл и вызывается снова, хотя я пишу `return count;` в конце функции `read()`, что является оптимальным вариантом(все данные получены) ?

Типовой цикл чтения «всего файла» до конца выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
char buf[BUF_SZ];

do {
  ssize_t sz = read(fd, buf,BUF_SZ);
  if (sz<0) {
    perror("read failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (sz==0) {
    break
  } else {
    processData(buf);
  }
} while (1);
```

т.е. признаком конца файла является то, что `read` вернул `0`. В случае в вопросе этого никогда не происходит т.е. файл оказывается бесконечный аналогично, например, `/dev/zero` или `/dev/urandom`; и `cat` повисает в таком же цикле...

> 3) зачем нам нужен `loff_t *f_pos`, если в файл мы все равно ничего не записываем (`если я правильно понимаю, то мы работаем с буфером пользовательского пространства, который предоставляет ядро и с буфером, который мы сами создаем, в нашем случае - my_driver_buf`) и нам необязательно знать позицию в нем (в данном примере по крайне мере) ?

`loff_t` является смещением в виртуальном файле, которое предоставляет устройство. Если устройство не хранит какое-либо внутреннее состояние, то на него необходимо ориентироваться дабы не возвращать каждый раз одинаковые данные. Например, в данном примере его было бы разумно интерпретировать, как смещение в буфере.

---

С учётом вышеописанного функция чтения будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
static ssize_t my_driver_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Function read() works and received %zu characters\n", count);

    if (*f_pos >= sizeof (my_driver_buf)) {
      printk(KERN_DEBUG "Trying to read beyond buffer end, returning 0 to indicate EOF\n");
      return 0;
    } else if (*f_pos+count > sizeof (my_driver_buf)) {
      count = sizeof (my_driver_buf) - *f_pos;
      printk(KERN_DEBUG "count is bigger than buffer size, trimed it to %d\n", count);
    }

    if (copy_to_user(buf, my_driver_buf+*f_pos, count)!=0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error in function copy_to_user()\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    *f_pos += count;
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: Где Вы писали f_pos, то имелось в виду *f_pos ?

Comment: @Антон, да, конечно, спасибо, поправил... ещё была ошибочка с тем что не учитывал это смещение в буфере...